# TextView Marquee and Digital Clock

Tags: android

When I use `Digital clock` and `textview marquee`, then `textview marquee` does not work- and If I remove digital clock it works perfectly.

```
 TextView tv = new TextView(this);

    tv.setLayoutParams(paramsSong);     
    tv.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    tv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    tv.setFreezesText(true);
    tv.setSingleLine(true);
    tv.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
    tv.setText("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    tv.setSelected(true);
            rl.addView(tv);

    DigitalClock dg = new DigitalClock(this);
            rl.addView(dg);

/*if I remove digital clock then it works*/
```

Can I not use both at the same time or Is there any solution?

Comment: Try setting constant size of DigitalClock (aka width and height)

Comment: r u setting the `LayoutParams` of the `DigitalClock` to right  or left of the `TextView` ?

Comment: @MarekSebera i Have to Know Something So please reply me i am testing it on Physical  Device (4.0.4) and its working fine with only `DigitalClock dg = new DigitalClock(this);
            rl.addView(dg);`  and it also works fine by Setting Height And Width

Comment: @bakriOnFire thanx it is working after giving params. could you please tell me why it is not working without giving params?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use these but first correct your mistakes

**1.** you are adding view  `rl.addView(tv);` 2 Times

**2.** set `Height` and `Width` of `DigitalClock`

Try Following code Which  is Working Fine for me

```
   TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    rl.addView(tv);// Here is Your Mistake ! Remove it 
    tv.setLayoutParams(paramsSong);     
    tv.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.MARQUEE);
    tv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    tv.setFreezesText(true);
    tv.setSingleLine(true);
    tv.setMarqueeRepeatLimit(-1);
    tv.setText("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
    tv.setSelected(true);
            rl.addView(tv);// Adding view Here is Absolutely Right ! 

    DigitalClock dg = new DigitalClock(this);
    dg.setHeight(setHeightHere);
    dg.setWidth(setWidthHere);
            rl.addView(dg);
```

**PS.** `DigitalClock class was deprecated in API level 17`

Docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DigitalClock.html

```
This class was deprecated in API level 17.
It is recommended you use TextClock instead.
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html

Comment: yes I removed it. But it is not working without giving width and height. as Marek said in comment- anyway +1 for help-

Comment: @TarunDroid but its (`DigitalClock`) working fine for me without setting Width and Height ! The Only thing Except My Answer  Which i have Take care is That is LayoutParams ! i.e. i Used `LinearLayout with orientation Vertical` so that `DigitalClock` can be shown below `TextView`